# new object as parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple one line function. Function received argument as an object and I am assigning a value to that object but it is alerting undefined. What is wrong with the code.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hchusz7/)

```
function custom(obj){
    obj.name="johnson";
}


var j= new custom(new Object());

alert(j.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors in your code:

1. `custom` function should `return obj;`

2. there's no reason to have `new custom` in `var j = new custom(new Object());`

This is the working version of your code:

```
  function custom(obj) {
    obj.name = "johnson";
    return obj;
  }

  var j = custom(new Object());

  console.log(j.name)
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're not returning the object:

```
function custom(obj){
    obj.name="johnson";
    return obj;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hchusz7/1/)

Comment: why we need to return obj. When we define function with this.name and use new operator then its work fine.

Comment: @amit Because `var j= new custom(new Object());`. The `=` there is expecting an object to be returned from the function. Otherwise, it returns nothing and `j` is assigned nothing.